# Error: ForeignKeyAttribute on property is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to 'get' an entity from a database using Entity Framework - that has a one to one relationship with another entity. There is a foreign key called "ImageId" on ContactModel, and yet I am getting this error:

> 'The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Image' on type
>   'Models.ContactModel' is not valid. The foreign key name 'ImageId' was
>   not found on the dependent type 'Models.ContactModel'. The Name value
>   should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.'

I am obviously doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

These are my entity classes:

```
 [Table("Contact")]
public class ContactModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual ImageModel Image { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContactImage")]
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestions would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should add another another property for the FK ID in the Contact Model, and decorate that with the FK attribute, such as:

```
[Table("Contact")]
public class ContactModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Image")]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    public virtual ImageModel Image { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If i remeber correctly you should have a property for the foreign key and a property for the image itself on the ContactModel class.

like so:

```
[Table("Contact")]
public class ContactModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string  Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }


    public string Email { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Image
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual ImageModel Image { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContactImage")]
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

With your current model you're saying that ContactModel have an Image of type ImageModel and it has a foreign key called ImageId, but the foreign key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/foreignkey-attribute It has several methods to indicate foreign key. I found indicating [ForeignKey("ClassName")] in the dependent class does not work in MVC5 .